# NPE in own realization of LinkedList (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm a beginner in programming and I need to write some kind of own LinkedList, but only with `add(E element)` method and with Iterator's `hasNext()` and `next()`. Here is my code:

```
  public class LinkedArray<E> implements Iterator<E> {

        private int size = 0;

        private int current = 0;

        private Node<E> first;

        private Node<E> last;

        private Objects[] objects = new Objects[10];

        public void add(E value) {
            Node<E> element = new Node<E>(last, value, null);
            if (last != null) {
                element.next = element;
            } else {
                first = element;
            }
            last = element;
            size++;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                if (objects[current + 1] != null) {
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            E result;
            try {
                current++;
                result = (get(current - 1));
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements in list.");
            }
            return result;
        }

   public E get(int position) throws NullPointerException {
        Object result;
    if (this.objects[position] != null) {
        result = this.objects[position];
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Position is empty.");
    }
    return (E) result;
}


        private class Node<E> {

            private E element;

            private Node<E> next;

            private Node<E> prev;

            Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
                this.element = element;
                this.next = next;
                this.prev = prev;
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I started to test add(E value)...

```
@Test
    public void test() {
        LinkedArray<String> arr = new LinkedArray<>();
        String string = "Test";

        arr.add(string);
        String result = arr.next();

        assertThat(result, is("Test"));
    }
```

...I only get an error. What the problem is, why am I getting it wrong?

Comment: post the error (stacktrace) you are getting

Comment: @hanumant it's just "java.lang.NullPointerException: Position is empty." in E get(int position) method.

Comment: then either it's not being added correctly or you are not accessing it correctly

Comment: please debug it once http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: @JFPicard, I know what npe means, I don't understand why it's here

Comment: Try to remove that line: throw new NullPointerException("Position is empty.");

Comment: Adding onto Brandon's, I dont see any point where you are writing a value into objects[], just reading

Comment: @blackHorsie The duplicate is both to explain what **and how** to fix. You've not posted the stacktrace, so please read that and see for yourself "why" it errors.

Comment: `element.next = element;` should be `last.next = element;` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've explicitly thrown your own NPE.

```
public E get(int position) throws NullPointerException {
    Object result;
    if (this.objects[position] != null) {
        result = this.objects[position];
    } else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Position is empty.");
    }
    return (E) result;
}
```

If you want to follow [the `get()` method contract of a `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-), the Javadoc says this

> **Throws:**
>   `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`

Therefore since you are not "referencing" anything that is `null`, and rather just going to `return null` in the case that your array is empty, then throw the other exception.

```
public E get(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (position < 0 || position >= this.objects.length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    return (E) this.objects[position];
}
```

Note: `Iterator` classes don't usually have a `E get()` method. Just `hasNext()` and `next()`

Therefore, you should not implement your class in a way that `next()` requires a call to `get()`.

You also need no `try-catch` there. You already know when `position` is out of bounds using if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get(...)` function reads the objects from the `objects` array.
You never set the contents of this array so if `position` is less then 10 it will always be `null` and cause the NPE you encountered.

It looks like you've adapted an array-based list but only changed the `add` method. All the other methods interact with the empty `objects` array.